# Adding custom HTML code (<track> tag) through Rails video_tag helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I am trying to add subtitles to a video on my Rails-powered website using "video_tag" (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-video_tag). This returns a HTML5 video tag. To add subtitles, though, you need to add a sub-node to the HTML5 tag as described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video:

```
<video id="video" controls preload="metadata">
   <source src="video/sintel-short.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="video/sintel-short.webm" type="video/webm">
   <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="captions/vtt/sintel-en.vtt" default>
</video>
```

The question is, how do I add another HTML tag through using Rails "video_tag" helper?

My current code is as follows:

```
<%= video_tag Video.last.file , size: "850x450", controls: true %>
```

And this generates the following HTML5 video tag:

```
<video controls="controls" width="850" height="450" src="/uploads/video/file/14/blah_blah.mp4"></video>
```

Not sure how I can fit in `<track>` tag inside Rails "video_tag". If I add another parameter to the helper, this simply produces another src HTML tag, and adding that as an option to the "video_tag" produces a HTML attribute, but not a child node.

I can obviously work around that by placing HTML code directly in my ERB template, but my assumption was that Rails "video_tag" helper should support this somehow. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am aware of "Video.last.file" in my example (which is not a correct way to display an uploaded video), this is for testing purposes only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only pass sources without any attributes in video_tag:

```
video_tag(["trailer.ogg", "trailer.flv"], size: "160x120")
# => <video height="120" width="160"><source src="/videos/trailer.ogg" /><source src="/videos/trailer.flv" /></video>
```

Rails source code:

```
if sources.size > 1
  content_tag(type, options) do
    safe_join sources.map { |source| tag("source", :src => send("path_to_#{type}", source)) }
  end
else
  options[:src] = send("path_to_#{type}", sources.first)
  content_tag(type, nil, options)
end
```

So HTML workaround is the only way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an HTML5 tag called track. Not really sure how to implement, I just started reading about this now. 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_track.asp

Comment: The question already mentions this tag as a way to work with subtitles and shows HTML snippet with it. I was asking if there's a native way to use the tag with a Rails helper. Anyway, that's now solved, I had to use raw HTML in the view template, not sure if later versions of Rails might have this fixed, though.